# What about the curve $yx^2=(1-y)^3$?

Tags: plane-curves, locus

Given a rectangle $ABCD$ with $A=(0,0), B=(t,0), C=(t,1)$ and $D=(0,1)$  for $0<t<\infty$ , let $P$ be the intersection of the diagonal $BD$ with the perpendicular to this diagonal by $C$. The locus of $P$ as $t$ varies is the curve $yx^2=(1-y)^3$. I'm looking for info on this curve (hoping that someone has already dealt with it!), be it historical (is it a well-known curve?) or as related to other geometrical loci. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curve you describe is a specific case of a [Cissoid of Diocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cissoid_of_Diocles).  Yours is rotated but the shape is the same.